# Proving that if $U \cap C \neq \varnothing$ then $U \subseteq C.$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and let $C \subseteq X$ be a connected component. Then for any connected set $U \subseteq X$ with $U \cap C \neq \varnothing$ show that $U \subseteq C.$

I am thinking along the following lines $:$

We write $U = (U \cap C) \cap (U \cap C^c).$ If $U \cap C^c \neq \varnothing$ I am trying to show that then $U$ would become disconnected. But for that we need to show that both $U \cap C$ and $U \cap C^c$ are clopen subsets of $U,$ which I can't quite able to conclude. Could anyone please give me some suggestion in this regard?

Thanks for investing your valuable time in reading my question.

**EDIT** $:$ What will happen if we draw two disjoint circles in the complex plane and join their centres by a straight line? Then the straight line will cut both the circles at a single point.

Comment: If you show that $U\cup C$ is connected, you will essentially be done. Have you tried that?

Comment: @keen-ameteur this is pretty easy to show. Now what to do?

Comment: Well, you've shown that $U\cup C$ is connected and $C\subseteq U\cup C$. Can it be that $C\nsubseteq U\cup C $  and $C$ is a connected component?

Comment: Oh I see. Due to maximality of $C$ we should have $U \cup C = C$ and hence $U \subseteq C.$ Done! Thanks for your help @keen-ameteur.

Comment: @Arthur connected components are trivially closed in any topological space. Because if $A$ is connected and $A \subseteq B \subseteq \overline {A}$ then $B$ is also connected. Also in a locally connected topological space connected components are open as well. So they are clopen in any locally connected topological space.

Answer (score 1):

If you define the component $C(x)$ as the maximal connected subset of the space that contains $x$, then by $C\cap U \neq \emptyset$, there exists $x\in U\cap C$ and since $U$ is connected it implies that $U\subseteq C$.